# DataFrame groupby 2 columns und count occurence in third

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to group a DataFrame by two columns and count the difference occurence in the third column. What I've got so far is:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': ['name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name4', 'name2', 'name5'], 'colB': ['red', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'black', 'yellow', 'green'], 'colC': ['value1', 'vlaue2', 'value2', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6']})

df_grouped = df.groupby(["colA", "colB"])["colC"].count()

print(df_grouped)
```

Where the output is:

```
colA   colB  
name1  red       1
name2  yellow    3
name4  black     1
name5  green     1
```

What I'm trying to do is, see colA and colB as 1 colum and count (and show) the occurance of the different values in colC. So in this case it shoud be:

```
    colA    colB    colC  count  
0  name1     red  value1  1
1  name2  yellow  vlaue2  2
2                 value5  1
3  name4   black  value4  1
4  name5   green  value6  1
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
What I also tried is this:

```
df["colAB"] = df["colA"].map(str) + " " + df["colB"]
df_grouped = df.groupby(["colAB", "colC"])["colC"].count().reset_index(name="count")
```

But it also didn't bring the right result. To be more specific. What I need is every value (colC) and the number how often it occurs for the combination of colA and colB. Even if there are 2 columns for colA and ColB the combination of the two is one distinct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just need to group by 3 col A,B and C:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(["colA", "colB","colC"])["colC"].count().reset_index(name="count")
```

```
Output :
>
    colA    colB    colC  count
0  name1     red  value1      1
1  name2  yellow  value2      2
2  name2  yellow  value5      1
3  name4   black  value4      1
4  name5   green  value6      1
```

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(["colA", "colB","colC"])["colC"].count()

> 
colA   colB    colC  
name1  red     value1    1
name2  yellow  value2    2
               value5    1
name4  black   value4    1
name5  green   value6    1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This might work. But what would be better if the combination of colA ans ColB only appears one time and can be grouped together and then only the different colCs are shown. In this case index 1 and 2 because there are a lot of entries. Maybe one have to group the result again?